# How to choose between geometric and negative binomial distributions

Tags: statistics

A sample question for an actuarial science exam [sample exam](https://www.beanactuary.org/how-do-i-get-started/is-this-the-career-for-you/sample-actuarial-problems/) goes like this:

"Calculate the probability that there will be at least four months in which no accidents occur before the fourth month in which at least one accident occurs.
A company takes out an insurance policy to cover accidents that occur at its manufacturing plant. The probability that one or more accidents will occur during any given month is 3/5.

The number of accidents that occur in any given month is independent of the number of accidents that occur in all other months."

I interpreted this as what is the probability (P) of no accidents during any of **at least** 3 months before one or more accidents occur in the following month.

I assumed a geometric distribution and calculated two different ways, got the same answer both times:

Given: "event": "one or more accidents in a month"
p(event) = 3/5;  q(non event) = 1-p = 2/5

1. One event occurs after 3 or more months of no events:   P = q^3*p*sum(k=0->inf)(q^k) = q^3*p*(1/(1-q)) = q^3 = (2/5)^3 = 0.064
2. P = 1 - Prob(one or more accidents occur in one or more of the first three months). Same answer: 0.064.

But 0.064 is not among the answer choices.

The exam offers its solution as using the negative binomial distribution as follows:

"Solution: D
If a month with one or more accidents is regarded as success and k = the number of failures before the fourth success, then k follows a negative binomial distribution and the requested probability is:

[image: solution 1]

Alternatively the solution is

[image: Solution 2]

which can be derived directly or by regarding the problem as a negative binomial distribution with

- success taken as a month with no accidents
- k = the number of failures before the fourth success, and calculating"

So my question is:  How to infer that the correct probability distribution to consider is the negative binomial ??  In my reading of the question, it is the **first** "success" not the **fourth** "success" that occurs after three failures hence geometric distribution (or, equivalently, (1,p) NB distribution).

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they asked to calculate the probability of the event before an Rth success occurs. So, the whole point of negative binomial distribution is to find the probabilities of events before Rth success in "N-R" trials. whereas it is quite different with geometric distribution where you find the probability of the first success.
I hope my explanation was understandable, also I just stumbled upon this.